# Get video duration from file location without using ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, duration

```
function getDuration($file){
        if (file_exists($file)){
         ## open and read video file
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        ## read video file size
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
        fclose($handle);
        $make_hexa = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($contents,strlen($contents)-3)));
        if (strlen($contents) > $make_hexa){
        $pre_duration = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($contents,strlen($contents)-$make_hexa,3))) ;
        $post_duration = $pre_duration/1000;
        $timehours = $post_duration/3600;
        $timeminutes =($post_duration % 3600)/60;
        $timeseconds = ($post_duration % 3600) % 60;
        $timehours = explode(".", $timehours);
        $timeminutes = explode(".", $timeminutes);
        $timeseconds = explode(".", $timeseconds);
        $duration = $timehours[0]. ":" . $timeminutes[0]. ":" . $timeseconds[0];}
        return $duration;
        }
        else {
        return false;
        }
}
```

This code is working fine but for some files it shows `variable $duration is undefined` even if the file exists! please help someone.

Source **[Daniweb](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/428301/getting-video-duration-without-ffmpeg)**

is there any other way to get the video duration ? 
and is it fast enough ?

Comment: i thought it will be slow as when converting a video .... it that  true ? @LordNeckbeard if not then how can i do with `ffmpeg` ?

Comment: See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration